# Pip - Change directory of pip cache on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I heard changing XDG_CACHE_DIR or XDG_DATA_HOME fixes that but I did

```
export XDG_CACHE_DIR=<new path>
export XDG_DATA_HOME=<new path>
```

I've also tried

```
pip cache dir --cache-dir <new path>
```

and

```
pip cache --cache-dir <new path>
```

and

```
--cache-dir <new path>
```

and

```
python --cache-dir <new path>
```

from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#cmdoption-cache-dir
and when I type

```
pip cache dir
```

It's still in the old location. How do I change the directory of pip cache?

Comment: have you tried --cache-dir [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#cmdoption-cache-dir)

Comment: @PaulBaiju yea I mentioned above that I have.

Comment: Not `pip cache --cache-dir <new path>` just `--cache-dir <new path>`

Comment: @PaulBaiju yea says "--cache-dir: command not found"

Comment: What @PaulBaiju is suggesting is `pip <command> --cache-dir <path>`. But this only affects the current command, not permanently AFAIK. For example `pip install something --cache-dir ~/.mycache`.

Comment: @GinoMempin I see, unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I need to change the location of pip cache. I'm not sure if he was suggesting that cause he didn't add 'pip <command>' to his suggestion.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*TL;TR;: do not change `XDG_CACHE_HOME` globally unless you are sure you really want to do that.*

---

Changing `XDG_CACHE_HOME` globally, like some people suggested would not only affect `pip` but also other apps as well. You simply do not want to mess that deep, because it's simply not necessary in most of the cases. So what are your alternatives then? You could be using `pip`'s `--cache-dir <dir>` command line argument instead or, at least, if you want to go that way, you could override `XDG_CACHE_HOME` value for `pip` invocation only:

```bash
XDG_CACHE_HOME=<path> pip ...
```

which also can be made more permanent by using shell `alias` feature:

```bash
alias pip="XDG_CACHE_HOME=<path> pip"
```

**BUT, but, but**... there is not need to touch `XDG_CACHE_HOME` at all, as `pip` can have own [configuration file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#configuration-files), in which you can override all of the defaults to match your needs, including alternative location of cache directory. Moreover, all command line switches have accompanying environment variables that `pip` checks at runtime, which looks like the cleanest approach for your tweakings.

In your particular case, `--cache-dir` can be provided via `PIP_CACHE_DIR` env variable. So you can either set it globally:

```bash
export PIP_CACHE_DIR=<path>
```

or per invocation:

```bash
PIP_CACHE_DIR=<path> pip ...
```

or, you create said pip's configuration file and set it there.

See [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables) for more information about `pip` config file and variables.

Answer (score 9):

To simplify the other answer:

```
# find the config file location under variant "global"
pip config list -v

# create the file and add
[global]
cache-dir=/path/to/dir

# test if it worked
pip config list
pip cache dir
```